# Access Internet Explorer History in Java

Tags: java, internet-explorer

After searching almost all the available options, I couldn't find a way to access internet explorer history using java. I need the URL and the start and close time of a link accessed via Internet Explorer. I am a newbie to Java, so help is requested.
PS: I know that the history files are saved somewhere in our computer and if no API is available then our program needs to access those files. 
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: They are stored in the user's SAM registry. You may need authentication.

Comment: Thank you @Mr.Polywhirl. Can you please help how can i get this file in java program and extract information from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on right way - history (actually cache) is in file system. But where on file system depends on Windows and IE version. Simplest way - do search on file system for some text on your cached page and you will easily find it. Here is text to search this page "abrakadabra" ;) Easy to find.